# Twitter hash value in URL not proper

Tags: javascript, webkit, v8

Debugging an issue in Android webkit and there is an issue as follows:

Login to twitter->Select Profile->Select profile image

Result: Redirected to a page which says "Sorry, that page doesn't exist"

After debugging on the live script found that _hash value is not coming properly from the twitter script.

Initial page - "https://mobile.twitter.com"
After selecting Profile - "https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/waptdpt" (waptdpt is the username)
After selecting the Profile pic - 
Expected URL is https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/waptdpt/photo
Resultant URL is https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/https://mobile.twitter.com/waptdpt/photo

After # the hash value has to be

> !/waptdpt/photo

. But in my case it is returning

!/https://mobile.twitter.com/waptdpt/photo

And hence i am being redirected to a wrong page.

There is something going wrong in the hash value generation. Any help?